# UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError when updating PFUser on Parse from Heroku node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, heroku, pfuser

I'm trying to update a PFUser in my Parse database from a node.js app running on Heroku. I'm calling the Parse cloud function from an iOS app.

Here's the part of the code I use to update the user on parse as well as creating the user on Stripe (the Stripe part works fine):

```
Parse.Cloud.define("createCustomerWithCreditCardToken", function(request, response) {
  var userId = request.user.id;
  var sourceId = request.params.creditCardToken;
  var customerId;
  var userSessionToken = request.user.getSessionToken();
  console.log('userId: ' + userId + ' source: ' + sourceId + ' userSessionToken: ' + userSessionToken);
  stripe.customers.create({
    source: sourceId,
    description: userId
  }, function(error, customer) {
    if (error !== null) {
      response.error('error creating customer: ' + error);
    }else {
      var userQuery = new Parse.Query('User');
      userQuery.equalTo('objectId', userId);
      userQuery.first({sessionToken: userSessionToken}).then(function(user) {
        console.log('user from parse query: ' + user.get("username"));
        user.set("stripeCustomerId", customer.id);
        user.save(null, {
          success: function(parseCustomer) {
            console.log('customer saved to parse: ' + parseCustomer);
          },
          error: function(error, parseCustomer) {
            console.log('customer save failed: ' + JSON.stringify(error, null, 2) + ' with error: ' + JSON.stringify(parseCustomer,null, 2));
          }
        });
      });
      customerId = customer.id;
      console.log('customerId: '+ customerId);
      // response.success(customer);
      response.success('Customer: ' + JSON.stringify(customer, null, 2) + 'error: ' + error);
    }
  });
});
```

I get the following error log output when I run this:
[error log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtQTR.png)

```
error: { "code": 206, "message": "Parse::UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError" }
```

In this [post](http://blog.parse.com/learn/using-node-js-with-parse/) the current user concept in a node.js app context is discussed by a Parse engineer.

> Also in Cloud Code, the concept of a method that returns the current
>   user makes sense, as it does in JavaScript on a web page, because
>   there’s only one active request and only one user. However in a
>   context like node.js, there can’t be a global current user, which
>   requires explicit passing of the session token.

Essentially he advises to do this:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('findBacon', function(req, res) {
var token = req.user.getSessionToken();
var query = new Parse.Query('Bacon');
// Pass the session token to the query
query.find({ sessionToken: token }).then( ... );
});
```

I have also tried using `{useMasterKey:true}` instead of `{sessionToken:userSessionToken}` which produces the same error.

I might just be missing some obvious detail, but I just can't seem to find it. Any ideas on how to solve this are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there's a third way of handling credentials:

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
```

I placed this line in the beginning of the entire method, that did it for me. I'm not sure of the implications of giving the whole function these credentials though.

I'm not sure when you would use the other options either.

If someone comes across this and would like to elaborate, I'll be happy to give the right answer to a good explanation of when to grant which credentials.